# Create TemplateRef in a Angular 10 service

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

We use ngZorro in an Angular 10 project. Now I want to open the drawer (https://ng.ant.design/components/drawer/en) to show forms. The scenario is a list of e.g. products and on a click on one of the product, it's form should be opened in the drawer.

I'm using the NzDrawerService to create the drawer, but I cannot set any footer (called nzFooter).

For example, there is a ProductFormComponent, so in my ProductService.ts I can just call:

```
openForm(){
  const drawerRef = this.drawerService.create({
      nzTitle: 'My Title',
      nzContent: ProductFormComponent
  });
  drawerRef.open()
}
```

Now, there is also an option for a predefined footer (`nzFooter?: string | TemplateRef<{}>`), where I want to add the buttons for save and cancel.
Now the question: How can I get a TemplateRef here, because the function is called in a service and not in a component?

Comment: how about passing a templateRef from the component which calls the function in the service (so instead of `openForm()`, do `openForm(template: TemplateRef<any>)`?

Comment: That‘s exactly what I want to prevent. Otherwise every component that uses the service (or even through other services) must have a template. And in a CRUD service this would always the same template for the save and cancel buttons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I had a single template I would want to inject to a service, I would use a "dummy" component, which I would use to inject a template into my service.

You can add a function on the drawer service to set a templateRef:

```
private template: TemplateRef<any>;
setTemplate(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  this.template = template;
}
```

the component would look like:

```
@Component({
  selector: "template-injector",
  template: `
    <ng-template #myTemplate>
      <h1>Best Template!</h1>
    </ng-template>
  `,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class TemplateInjectorComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private derviceService: DrawerService) {}

  @ViewChild("myTemplate") template: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.derviceService.setTemplate(this.template);
  }
}
```

and finally, find the main component in your app and load the TemplateInjectorComponent, since the template is just `<ng-template>`, nothing is rendered (a good place to add it would be at the end of your layout component).

Alternatively, instead of creating a new component, you can add it to the main app component.

Comment: That could be a solution. Am I right that there could only be one template at once?

Comment: with the listed solution, but you can extend it and create an object with many templates (or array, or Record), I was just trying to convey the general idea, but then you also have to specify the template when opening